# Set ‘Allow service to interact with Desktop’ for a newly created windows service at install time

Tags: windows-installer, setup-deployment

When using VS setup and deployment project for creating windows installer database file, how to set a windows service to ‘Allow service to interact with Desktop’. I am using System.Configuration.Install.Installer derived class to install a new windows service. This installer class gets invoked as a custom action. I did not found any property on installer class that could solve the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are three different programmatic methods -- registry, WMI, and comamnd-line tool -- in the 2010 C#-Corner article  [Allow windows service to "Interact with desktop"](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Yousafi/allow-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop/).

I haven't actually tried them out; I found both the article and and your question when I was trying to add this functionality to my installer, but testing showed I didn't actually need that setting.